# as3 flash - projector using up down arrows

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using flash cc and know how to do the below in as2 but not as3.

what is the code so i can use keyboard commands up and down arrows to move to next frame forward and back in the timeline. this is for mac and win projector files?

Comment: Showing how you would do it in as2 would definitely increase the chances of someone translating that script. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of capturing key input in AS3:

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

//add the a key listener to the stage,  OR if using AIR you could add it to NativeApplication.nativeApplication to be truly global.
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        case Keyboard.UP:
        case Keyboard.PAGE_UP:
            //up or right or pageup was pressed
            nextFrame();
            break;

        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        case Keyboard.PAGE_DOWN:
            //down or left or pagedown was pressed
            prevFrame();
            break;
    }
}
```